# Angular & Firestore - A ServiceWorker intercepted the request and encountered an unexpected error

Tags: angular, firefox, google-cloud-firestore, angular-service-worker

packages:

```
"@angular/core": "~10.0.1",
"@angular/service-worker": "~10.0.1",
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
"firebase": "^7.14.0"
```

I´ve an Angular application with Firebase as a serverless backend solution. I use Firestore as the database with offline caching enabled:

```
AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),
```

Additionally, I imported the Angular service worker:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: env.production, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' }),
```

However, there seems to be an issue when service worker and Firestore offline persistence are running simultaneously, because I get following error in Firefox:

```
Failed to load 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2F*APP*%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&gsessionid=o0mUQ2DH6MnytwOUf0E_pe_hDNabWoSV&VER=8&RID=rpc&SID=tO_GFPEz5AACUo42a8LC7A&CI=0&AID=20&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=zbgjb7rtyxyp&t=11'. A ServiceWorker intercepted the request and encountered an unexpected error.
```

Additionally new content is only loaded when refreshing the whole page multiple times.

Comment: Have you been able to successfully run your Application without the workers? I mean just with Firestore+Angular?

Also, have you tried to run it on a different browser?

Comment: Yeah the service worker was added just recently. It seems like all browsers have this behaviour, but only Firefox throws this error.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue..

Comment: The only solution that helped for me was implementing a Listener for ServiceWorker Updates. I can add it as an answer if you still need it.

Comment: It's been over a year but I have the exact same issue. Would appreciate an answer!